# Es aconsejable usar AJAX anidados?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Compañeros tengo la siguiente inquietud. Tengo un archivo donde tengo todo el HTML para tomar los datos de un cliente. Ahora bien, con el fin de modular el código, le cree varios archivos de la siguiente manera:
1 - cliente_add_save.php: Donde guardo los datos principales de los clientes.
2 - cliente_direccion_add_save.php: Una vez que se guarden los datos principales del cliente, se guardan las direcciones que pueden ser más de uno y los capturo con unos inputs tipo array
3 - cliente_contacto_add_save.php: Una vez que se guarden todas las direcciones se guardan los contactos asociados al cliente que igualmente pueden ser más de uno.

Tenía la idea inicial de:

```
$(document).on('click', '#guardar', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    /** INICIO DE DECLARACIÓN Y CAPTURA DE LOS VALORES IMPORTANTES PARA PODER GUARDAR EN LA BASE DE DATOS **/
    var nombre_cliente = $('#cliente_nuevo').val(), comercial_nuevo = $('#comercial_nuevo').val();
    var IDType = $('#IDType').val(), numberID = $('#numberID').val(), DIV = $('#DIV').val(), sector = $('#sector').val();
    var id_sector = $('#lista_sector'+' [value="' + sector + '"]').data('id'), tipo = $('#tipo_cliente').val();
    var id_tipo = $('#lista_tipo'+' [value="' + tipo + '"]').data('id'), clasificacion = $('#clasificacion').val();
    var id_clasificacion = $('#lista_clasificacion'+' [value="' + clasificacion + '"]').data('id');
    var website_new = $('#website_new').val(), comercial = $('#comercial_user').val(), validar_razon = 0;
    var id_comercial = $('#list_comercial'+' [value="' + comercial + '"]').data('id'), validarComercial = 0;
    var comercial1 = '', fila_direccion = $('#tbody_direccion tr').length;//Se capturan los datos de las direcciones
    var dir_tipo = $("input[name='tipo_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var dir_completa = $("input[name='completo_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var pais_sigla = $("input[name='paiss_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var pais_id = $("input[name='paisi_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var region_id = $("input[name='region_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var dpto_id = $("input[name='dpto_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var ciudad_id = $("input[name='ciudad_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");  
    var localidad_id = $("input[name='localidadid_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var barrio_nombre = $("input[name='barrion_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var barrio_id = $("input[name='barrioi_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var telp = $("input[name='telefonop_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var movilp = $("input[name='movil_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var tels = $("input[name='telefonos_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var emailp = $("input[name='email_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var postal = $("input[name='postal_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var fila_contacto = $('#tbody_contactos tr').length;//Se toman los datos de los contactos
    var id_contacto = $("input[name='id_contacto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var etiqueta_id = $("input[name='etiquetei_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var etiqueta_nombre = $("input[name='etiqueten_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var nombre_contacto = $("input[name='nombre_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var apellido_contacto = $("input[name='apellido_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var identiciacion_contacto = $("input[name='id_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var telp_contacto = $("input[name='telefonopc_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var tels_contacto = $("input[name='telefonosc_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var fax_contacto = $("input[name='faxc_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var movilc_contacto = $("input[name='movilc_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var ext_contacto = $("input[name='extc_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var emailp_contacto = $("input[name='emailpc_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var emails_contacto = $("input[name='emailsc_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var cargo_contacto = $("input[name='cargoc_oculto[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var direciones = $("#dirc_oculto").val(), fila_actividads = $('#tbody_actividad tr').length;//Se toman las actividades y subactividades del cliente
    var nombre_actividadc = $("input[name='actividad[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var nombre_subactividadc = $("input[name='subactividad[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var id_actividadc = $("input[name='id_actividad[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var id_subactividadc = $("input[name='id_subactividad[]']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
    var notas = $('#notes_new').val(), sigla_pais = '', validarId = 0, mensajeId = '', validarNumero = 0;
    var mensajeNumero = '', validarDiv = 0, mensajeDiv = '', validarActividad = 0, mensajeActividad = '';
    var validarSubActividad = 0, mensajeSubActividad = '';
    $("#tbody_direccion tr").each(function(index) { //Se captura la sigla del país de la direccion del RUT
        var tipdir = $(this).find('td:eq(8)').text();
        if (tipdir=='RUT'){//Se encuentra la dirección del RUT
           sigla_pais = $(this).find('input[name="paiss_oculto[]"]').val();
           return false;
        }
     });
     $("#tbody_actividad tr").each(function(index) { //Se recorre la tabla que contiene los inputs de llla actividad y subactividad economica
     var input_actividad = $(this).find('input[name="actividad[]"]');//Input que tiene las actividades
     var input_subactividad = $(this).find('input[name="subactividad[]"]');//Input que tiene las subactividades
     var list_subactividad = $(this).find('datalist[name="list_subactividad[]"]');//Datalist que contiene las subactividades
     var valor_actividad = input_actividad.val(), valori_actividad = $('#list_actividad'+' [value="' + valor_actividad + '"]').data('id')
     var valor_subactividad = input_subactividad.val(), datalistSuffix = list_subactividad.attr('id').split('_').pop();
     // Buscar el ID de la subactividad utilizando el sufijo del datalist
     var valori_subactividad = $('#list_subactividad_' + datalistSuffix + ' [value="' + valor_subactividad + '"]').data('id');
            
     if (valor_actividad.trim()==''){//Se valida que la actividad principal no sea nulo
        validarActividad = 1;
        mensajeActividad = 'La actividad principal es obligatoria';
        return false;
     }else if (valor_actividad.trim()!=='' && valori_actividad==undefined){//Se valida que la actividad ingresada sea vválida
        validarActividad = 1;
        mensajeActividad = 'La actividad principal ingresada es inválida';
        return false;
     }else{
        validarActividad = 0;
        mensajeActividad = '';
     }
     if (valor_subactividad.trim()==''){//Se valida que la actividad secundaria no sea nulo
         validarSubActividad = 1;
         mensajeSubActividad = 'La actividad secundaria es obligatoria';
         return false;
     }else if (valor_subactividad.trim()!=='' && valori_subactividad==undefined){//Se valida que la subactividad ingresada sea vválida
         validarSubActividad = 1;
         mensajeSubActividad = 'La actividad secundaria ingresada es inválida';
         return false;
     }else{
         validarSubActividad = 0;
         mensajeSubActividad = '';
     }
  });
  /** FINALIZACIÓN DE DECLARACIÓN Y CAPTURA DE LOS VALORES IMPORTANTES PARA PODER GUARDAR EN LA BASE DE DATOS **/
        
  /** ========== INICIO VALIDACIONES DE LOS CAMPOS OBLIGATORIOS ========== **/
  if (sigla_pais=='CO'){//Para Colombia hay unos campos obligatorios
            if (IDType=='0'){//El tipo de identificación es obligatorio
                validarId = 1;
                mensajeId = 'El tipo de identificación es obligatorio';
            }else{
                validarId = 0;
                mensajeId = '';
            }
            if (numberID.trim()==''){//El número de identificación es obligatorio
                validarNumero = 1;
                mensajeNumero = 'El número de identificación es obligatorio';
            }else{
                validarNumero = 0;
                mensajeNumero = '';
            }
            if (DIV.trim()=='' && IDType=='NIT'){//Si el tipo de identificación es NIT, se debe ingresar el dígito de verificación
                validarDiv = 1;
                mensajeDiv = 'El dígito de verificación es obligatorio';
            }else{
                validarDiv = 0;
                mensajeDiv = '';
            }
        }else{
            validarId = 0;
            validarNumero = 0;
            validarDiv = 0;
        }
        if ($('#comercial_user1').length > 0){//Si el cliente tiene asignado dos comerciales, se capturan los datos
            comercial1 = $('#comercial_user1').val(), id_comercial1 = $('#list_comercial1'+' [value="' + comercial1 + '"]').data('id');
            validarComercial = 1;
        }else{
            comercial1 = '';//Se deja nulo el valor
            validarComercial = 0;
        }
        var razon = $('input:radio[name=razon]:checked').val();
        if ( razon == 'Si' ) {//Si el cliente está asociado a más de una razón social.
            var cliente_razon = $('#clientes_razon').val(), id_cliente_razon =  $('#lista_buscar_razon'+' [value="' + cliente_razon + '"]').data('id')
            fila_razon = $('#tabla_razon tr').length;
            if ( fila_razon == 0 ) {
                validar_razon = 1;
            }else {
                validar_razon = 0;
                var nombres_razones = $('label[name="mostrar_razon[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).text();}).get().join(";");
                var ids_razones = $('input[name="razon_id[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(";");
            }
        }else {
            nombres_razones = 'NULL';
            ids_razones = 'NULL';
        }
        if ( nombre_cliente == '' ) {//Se valida que el nombre del cliente haya sido ingresado
            $('#cliente_nuevo').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'El nombre del cliente es obligatorio.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (validarId==1){//El tipo de identificación es obligatorio para Colombia
            $('#IDType').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: mensajeId,showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (validarNumero==1){//El número de identificación es obligatorio para Colombia
            $('#numberID').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: mensajeNumero,showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (validarDiv==1){//El dígito de verificación es obligatorio para Colombia y cuando el tipo de documento es NIT
            $('#DIV').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: mensajeDiv,showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (sector.trim()==''){//El sector del cliente es obligatorio
            $('#sector').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'El sector del cliente es obligatorio.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (sector.trim()!=='' && id_sector==undefined){//El sector del cliente es un campo obligatorio
            $('#sector').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Debe seleccionar un sector válido.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (tipo.trim()==''){//El tipo de cliente es obligatorio
            $('#tipo_cliente').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'El tipo de cliente es obligatorio.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (tipo.trim()!=='' && id_tipo==undefined){//El tipo de cliente es un cammpo obligatorio
            $('#tipo').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Debe seleccionar un tipo de cliente válido.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (clasificacion.trim()==''){//La clasificación del cliente es obligatorio
            $('#clasificacion').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'La clasificación del cliente es obligatoria.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (clasificacion.trim()!=='' && id_clasificacion==undefined){//La clasificación del cliente es obligatorio
            $('#clasificacion').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Debe seleccionar una clasificacion de cliente válido.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (comercial.trim()==''){//Se valida que el comercial haya sido asignado
            $('#comercial_user').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'El asesor comercial es un campo obligatorios.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if ( comercial.trim() !== ''  && id_comercial == undefined ){//Se valida que el comercial ingresado sea válido
            $('#comercial_user').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'El comercial seleccionado es inválido.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (validarComercial==1 && comercial1.trim()==''){//Se valida que e segundo comercial haya sido asignado
            $('#comercial_user1').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'El segundo comercial es un campo obligatorio.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (validarComercial==1 && comercial1.trim()!=='' && id_comercial1==undefined){//Si el cliente es mixto: Textil y Publicidad, se debe agregar el segundo comercials
            $('#comercial_user1').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'El segundo comercial seleccionado es inválido.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if ( razon == undefined || razon == '' ) {//Se valida el radio de si el cliente tenga o no más de una razón social haya sido seleccionado
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Debe indicar si el cliente tiene o no más de una razón social.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if ( validar_razon == 1 ) {//Si el cliente esta asociado a más de una razón social, se valida que se ingrese al menos una razón social
            $('#clientes_razon').focus();
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Debe seleccionar al menos una raaón social.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if ( fila_direccion == 0 ){//Se valida que se haya ingresado al menos una dirección
            openCcontents(event, 'address_tab');
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Debe ingresar al menos una direccion.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (fila_contacto == 0) {//Se valida que se haya ingresado al menos un contacto
            openCcontents(event, 'contact_tab');
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Debe ingresar al menos un contacto.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (fila_actividads == 0){//Se valida que haya ingresado al menos una actividad comercial
            openCcontents(event, 'contact_tab');
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Debe ingresar al menos una actividad para el cliente.',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (validarActividad==1){//Se valida que se hayan ingresado actividad comercial válida
            openCcontents(event, 'activity_tab');
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: mensajeActividad,showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else if (validarSubActividad==1){//Se valida que se hayan ingresado actividad comercial válida
            openCcontents(event, 'activity_tab');
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
            Swal.fire({icon: 'info',title: 'AVISO',html: mensajeSubActividad,showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
        }else{
            //Se declaran las variables para ser enviadas por AJAX al archivo "cliente_add_save.php"
            var dataString='canal='+canal+'&userid='+userid+'&user_final='+user_final+'&nombre_cliente='+nombre_cliente+
            '&comercial_nuevo='+comercial_nuevo+'&IDType='+IDType+'&numberID='+numberID+'&DIV='+DIV+'&website_new='+website_new+
            '&notas='+notas+'&sector='+sector+'&id_sector='+id_sector+'&tipo='+tipo+'&id_tipo='+id_tipo+'&clasificacion='+clasificacion+
            '&id_clasificacion='+id_clasificacion+'&comercial='+comercial+'&id_comercial='+id_comercial+'&comercial1='+comercial1+
            '&id_comercial1='+id_comercial1+'&razon='+razon+'&nombres_razones='+nombres_razones+'&ids_razones='+ids_razones;
            //Ajax para enviar los datos y posteriormente ser ingresados a la BD
            $.ajax({
                url: "cliente_add_save.php",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: dataString,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
                },
                success: function(data){
                    if (data.val==0){//El registro se realizó exitosamente
                        id_cliente = data.id;//Se captura el ID del cliente ingresado
                        //Se prepara AJAX para guardar la(s) dirección(es) asociadas al cliente
                        var dataStringDir = 'id_cliente='+id_cliente+'&dir_tipo='+dir_tipo+'&dir_completa='+dir_completa+
                        '&pais_sigla='+pais_sigla+'&pais_id='+pais_id+'&region_id='+region_id+'&dpto_id='+dpto_id+
                        '&ciudad_id='+ciudad_id+'&localidad_id='+localidad_id+'&barrio_nombre='+barrio_nombre+
                        '&barrio_id='+barrio_id+'&telp='+telp+'&movilp='+movilp+'&tels='+tels+'&emailp='+emailp+
                        '&postal='+postal+'&user_final='+user_final+'&userid='+userid+'&nombre_cliente='+nombre_cliente;
                        $.ajax({//AJAX para guardar las direcciones en la BD
                            url: "cliente_add_direccion_save.php",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: dataStringDir,
                            success: function(dataDir){
                                var dataStringCon = 'id_contacto='+id_contacto+'&etiqueta_id='+etiqueta_id+'&nombre_contacto='+nombre_contacto+
                                '&apellido_contacto='+apellido_contacto+'&identiciacion_contacto='+identiciacion_contacto+
                                '&telp_contacto='+telp_contacto+'&tels_contacto='+tels_contacto+'&fax_contacto='+fax_contacto+
                                '&movilc_contacto='+movilc_contacto+'&ext_contacto='+ext_contacto+'&emailp_contacto='+emailp_contacto+
                                '&user_final='+user_final+'&userid='+userid+'&id_cliente='+id_cliente+'&nombre_cliente='+nombre_cliente+
                                '&emails_contacto='+emails_contacto+'&cargo_contacto='+cargo_contacto+'&direciones='+direciones;
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR2,textStatus2,errorThrown2) {
                                Swal.fire({icon: 'error',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Se produjo el error: '+jqXHR2.status+'-'+textStatus2+' al asociar la(s) direccion(es) al nuevo cliente',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 2000});
                            }
                        });
                        
                    }else{
                        $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
                        Swal.fire({icon: 'error',title: 'AVISO',text: data.mensaje,showConfirmButton: false,timer: 1500});
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR1,textStatus1,errorThrown1) {
                    $('#guardar').attr('disabled', false);
                    Swal.fire({icon: 'error',title: 'AVISO',html: 'Se produjo el error: '+jqXHR1.status+'-'+textStatus1+' al agregar el nuevo cliente',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 2000});
                },
                complete: function(xhr) {
                    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Sé que el código es bastante extenso y por eso recurro a ustedes si saben de alguna manera de que pueda mejorar y/u optimizar el código. Por otro lado, he leído en varios foros y no recomiendan que se usen AJAX anidados. Que en su lugar usara funciones asíncronas: async/await. Espero que me haya hecho entender

Comment: Ese código se **DEBE** mejorar, te recomiendo preguntar específicamente por eso, pero agregando un [MCVE], es decir sin poner todo ese código que has puesto ahora. Con relación a "ajax aninado", no entiendo donde está la anidación, además la función ajax de jQuery por default es asincrona

Comment: Ya vi la anidación, algún motivo del porque no guardar todo en una sola llamada ajax?

Comment: asi como esta, la pregunta esta basada en opiniones.. sin embargo, la mala idea puede venir por varios lados.. y pienso en voz alta, y es mi opinion, y no quiere decir nada.. pero si una pantalla tiene tantos datos.. no suena a buena idea... sobre todo poque al estar relacionados los datos, deberian todos guardarse atomicamente.. o estar en todas pantallas distintas...

Comment: Las llamadas a Ajax son asíncronas. Eso implica que si metes una llamada a Ajax dentro de otra llamada a Ajax va a ser muy complicado controlar cuál de ellas dos se completó primero. Pueden ocurrir cosas como que la segunda llamada se complete antes que la primera. Aparte de eso, en este caso no tiene sentido mandar los datos en varias etapas. ¿Acaso no sabes de antemano qué datos se van a mandar? Entonces prepara todos esos datos y haz un solo envío. Es como si en la vida real mandaras mercancía en varios vehículos/conductores cuando los puedes mandar en un solo vehículo/conductor.

Comment: La idea de tenerlo en diferentes archivos es para modular el código para su entendimiento y mantenimiento. Por eso no uso el mismo AJAX para guardar todo, ya que tengo varios archivos: cliente_add_save.php, cliente_contacto_add.php y cliente_direccion_add.php; a parte de que si coloco todo en el mismo archivo se volvería aún más extenso el archivo.